# How does "group by" work in LINQ? Error "'object' does not contain a definition for 'type'"

Tags: linq, entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-4

I just cannot understand why it works. I had this error

> 'object' does not contain a definition for 'type'

And it was because I was returning an anonymous type:

```
Connection db = new Connection();

public ActionResult Index()
{
    ViewBag.query = from input in db.field
                    where input.ID_FIELD == 1
                    select new 
                    {
                        type = input.FIELD_TYPE
                    };

    return View();
}


 @foreach (var item in ViewBag.query)
 {
     @item.type // Error here: 'object' does not contain a definition for 'type',
 }
```

So I added a class to get the types

```
public class Types
{
    public string type {get; set;}

    // And bla blab bla
}
```

Good, no problem. But now I need a group by clouse, but I don’t know how to do it.

For example, see the example 2 of this [link](http://href=%22http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/101-LINQ-Samples-3fb9811b). As you can see, everything works great, but here he didn’t have to specify the type, and it worked OK.

The following is my example. How can I use *Group By* with LINQ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`group x by x.PropertyName into g` will result in `g` being a collection of `x` objects with a property `Key` that will return the `x.PropertyName` value that was used to group the `x` objects

```
        ViewBag.query = from input in db.field
                        where input.ID_FIELD == 1
                        group input by input.FIELD_TYPE into g
                        select new {
                            FieldType = g.Key,
                            Fields = g
                        };
```

Comment: orderby x.PropertyName descending